# How do I compile C programs using Vim's 'make' command with Visual Studio's compiler on Windows 7?

Tags: c, vim, windows-7

I'm trying to set up Vim to user VS (express) C compiler `cl.exe`.  Adding

```
set makrprg='c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe'
```

(I've tried escaping with `\\`, `\\\`, `\\\\` just to be sure) to my `_vimrc` file and invoking `:make %` returns the following:

```
:! myfile.c >C:\Users\gvkv\AppData\Local\Temp\VIe7BF5.tmp 2>&1
```

and the loads `myfile.c` into VS's IDE!  Even if `cl.exe` needs its environment:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat
```

this is still strange and I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Instead of escaping the backslashes, try flipping the slashes in the other direction (Windows can handle this).  Also, most Make programs have debugging options; these can be helpful in tracking down problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem with your **makeprg** statement is mostly due to the spaces in the path.  *Cmd.exe* requires double quotes around the spaces. First, use escaped double quotes around the path (\"). Next escape all back slashes (\). Finally, escape all spaces (\ ).

```
set makrprg=\"c:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 10.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe\"
```

Alternatively, you could setup your **PATH** appropriately and just set **makeprg** to *cl.exe* directly.

Answer (score 6):

Judge Maygarden's solution is correct up to proper escaping and solved the Vim problem I had but there were a couple of other issues that I had to resolve to make things work.  In particular

1. `cl.exe` requires the correct environment as well as the correct path; i.e., adding `C:\my\path\to\cl` isn't sufficient.  Otherwise you will get errors reporting on missing `DLL`s.  The solution is to run `vcvars32.bat` (or any other batch file which sets up a similar environment) and `cl` as a single command.
2. `cmd` requires any paths with spaces to be double quoted but you can't escape them with `\` because `:! ...` treats `\` literally; instead, you must double quote the double quote, `""...`.

So, for completeness I thought I'd post my actual solution.  In Vim (or `_vimrc`):

```
:set makeprg=\"\"Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 10.0\\VC\\bin\\vcvars32.bat\"\&\&cl\"
```

and then you can simply call

```
:make %
```

and you're done.

This method is easily generalizable for any compiler.  Also, as devemouse's answer suggests, creating a makefile for `nmake` is probably the best way to go about doing things for any non-trivially sized project (I wanted a Vim-only solution that suits my current work).

Answer (score 3):

I created a **makefile** where I had such target:

```
VCPROJ = /path/to/MyProject.vcproj

all:
    "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe" /nocolor /r $(VCPROJ) Debug

.PHONY: all
```

I had `make` in vim's path so did not have to modify `makeprg`.

This way VS compiled normally whole project and vim parsed the errors.